# Convert Subject/Publisher to another Publisher

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

Given an existing `CurrentValueSubject` instance, the goal is to create a new `Publisher` that will take the subject's stream of Strings, and in turn will output Ints.

My approach is to map the subject to `AnyPublisher`:

```
let subject: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never> = ...

func intPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never>
{
    return subject.map { string in
        let value = Int(string) ?? 0
        return AnyPublisher<Int, Never>(value) // Error: Generic parameter P could not be inferred.
    }
}
```

However, I cannot create a new `AnyPublisher` this way. Clearly, my understanding of Publishers is flawed. Could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just a bit off.

`.map` maps values, so you need to return a new value, not a new publisher. Then use `.eraseToAnyPublisher` to create the `AnyPublisher` publisher:

```
func intPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
   subject.map { Int($0) ?? 0 }
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

You can also use `AnyPublisher(subject.map { Int($0) ?? 0 })` as well (the init parameter is a publisher, not a value).

---

For completeness, you *can* return a publisher for each value, but then you'd need to use a `flatMap`. The following achieves the same result as above, but just in an unnecessarily convoluted way:

```
subject.flatMap { string in
      Just( Int(string) ?? 0 )
   }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: The part about flatMap helped me a lot! Thank you. I tried to combine (zip) a second publisher per value of the main publisher to make a second network call and pass the received data  to the model I received with the first network call.